# Jumping to method definition in sublimeText2

Tags: methods, sublimetext2

SublimeText 2 is awesome and am really enjoying it for my ROR development. I was wondering whether there was a way for me to highlight a method call in some file and then it will take me its associated method definition in another file. I tried the GOTO [command + R] but it seems to only work in the context of the file that I am working in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [CTags](https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags) plugin for that. Once installed, you can jump to methods defined in different files with

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>.

An alternative, that is simpler to install, since it has no external dependencies, is [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel), but it has never worked reliably enough, at least on my machine.